# What is wrong with this LLVM IR code

Tags: c, llvm, intermediate-code

I have an LLVM IR code that looks something like this.

```
  %8 = load i64* @tid, align 8
  %arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds [16 x i32]* @h, 
    i32 0, i64 %8 ;<-- %8 works fine here
  ..............
  %OldFuncCounter7 = load i64* getelementptr inbounds ([16 x i64]* 
    @EdgeProfCounters, i64 0, i64 %8) ;<-- error here, %8 not allowed
  ..............
```

In the line where *arrayidx1* is assigned, everything is fine, but for *OldFuncCounter7*, the LLVM compiler complains by saying "invalid use of function-local name". It is due to the %8 I am using. If i replace it with a constant, it works fine. So my question is why is that %8 works fine with *arrayidx1*, but not with *OldFuncCounter7*. What is going on here?

The whole basic block where this error occurs is shown below

```
  %8 = load i64* @tid, align 8
  %arrayidx1 = getelementptr inbounds [16 x i32]* @h, i32 0, i64 %8
  store volatile i32 3, i32* %arrayidx1, align 4
  %9 = load volatile i32* getelementptr inbounds ([16 x i32]* @h, i32 0, i64 0), align 4
  %call2 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([10 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %9)
  %10 = load i64* @tid, align 8
  store volatile i64 %10, i64* %clock, align 8
  %call3 = call i32 @getpid() nounwind
  %call4 = call i64 @pthread_self() nounwind readnone
  %11 = load volatile i64* %clock, align 8
  %call5 = call i32 (i8*, ...)* @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([21 x i8]* @.str1, i32 0, i32 0), i32 %call3, i64 %call4, i64 %11)
  store i64 0, i64* %oi, align 8
  ; Error here due to %8
  %OldFuncCounter7 = load i64* getelementptr inbounds ([16 x i64]* @EdgeProfCounters, i64 0, i64 %8)
  ;
  %NewFuncCounter8 = add i64 %OldFuncCounter7, 13
  store volatile i64 %NewFuncCounter8, i64* getelementptr inbounds ([16 x i64]* @EdgeProfCounters, i64 0, i64 0)
  br label %for.cond6
```

Comment: can you paste a minimal but complete module that produces this problem?

Comment: Eli, now I've added the whole basic block.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `%8` from within a [constant expression](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constantexprs), but it is not a constant. You need to fix your code to perform the `getelementptr` instruction outside of a constant expression:

```
%temp = getelementptr inbounds [16 x i64]* @EdgeProfCounters, i64 0, i64 %8
%OldFuncCounter7 = load i64* %temp
```